# How to fix location of button in panel asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add dynamic button in panel

```
     <asp:Panel ID="pnl001" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="1174px"  ></asp:Panel>
```

How can i fix position (Left,Right,Top from panel) of that button

Please suggest

Comment: Are you saying you want to **anchor** the button in a certain position?

Comment: how are you adding dynamic button,please show the code.

Comment: yes i am trying to anchor buton in certain position

Comment: adding button like this       pnl001.Controls.Add(btn)

Answer (score 1):

Give the panel and your button a class (IDs can sometimes be tricky with Web Forms:

```
  <asp:Panel ID="pnl001" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="1174px" CssClass="MyPanel" >
      <asp:Button ID="myButton" Text="Click Me" CssClass="MyButton" />
  </asp:Panel>
```

Now you need to add some styles to your `<head>` element or your stylesheet:

```
  <style type="text/css">
  .MyPanel { position:relative; }
  .MyButton { 
             position:absolute;
             top:0;
             left:0;
            }
  </style>
```

**UPDATE**

Since you are adding the button dynamically, remember to add the class like this in your code-behind:

```
 btn.CssClass = "MyButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you might be adding button to your pannel like this

```
Button btn = new Button ();
btn.Text = "mytext";
btn .ID = "btn1";
btn.CssClass="MyCSSClassName";
pnl001.Controls.Add(btn);
```

now before `pnl001.Controls.Add(btn);` add this line `btn.CssClass="MyCSSClassName";` and add the following class in your stylesheet

```
<style type="text/css">

  .MyCSSClassName{ 
             //your properties for positioning the button inside a panel
            }
  </style>
```

hope this works for you.